# tortoiseSVN / automaticlly script which commit & ignore confilcts

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I generated a code every day, and I want to create a script which automatically do commit for this code.

My big problem is that some classes are changed, and there are a conflicts between the versions. Anyway, I want to ignore these conflicts and commit the last version, entirety.

is it possible to do this automatically? I run my code in `Eclipse`, use `tortoiseSVN`  on Windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

The [`svn resolve`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.resolve.html) command will allow you to resolve conflicts and with the correct parameters ([`--accept mine-full`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.accept)) you will tell it to use your version of the file. That you can then use in a script or similar to solve what you need.

However, I would be very careful in doing that because what you will possibly do is to overwrite other team members changes. If they have edited multiple parts in a class that are relying on each other and you only have conflict one one of those changes it is also possible that you will break the class making in uncompilable.